# Google reCaptcha v3 Challenge?

Tags: recaptcha, verification

We have added google reCaptcha v3 to our sign-in and have received some complaints from customers that they are being blocked. From what I understand this can happen if they are using the browser incognito mode as well as if they are using a VPN.

With that said, is there away to weed out the good traffic from the bad if google declares the traffic to be suspect ~ i.e. adding a visual challenge and / or adding some type of verification if the score is under a certain threshold?

If so does anyone have a walk through or experience in implementing this type of verification within the latest reCaptcha? The documentation of this is rather limited and does not provide any real world examples of what to do in this circumstance.

Any help or guidance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found some info - the Google docs says it's possible to issue a challenge with reCaptcha 3.

> https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify

I wonder if anyone has set up a working example of this?